# Amstrong number using lambda Expressions in Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, functional-programming, integer

I am fairly new to functional programming. Following is my code to check the sum of powered digits(Arsmstrong number check). Number is an input for example: 370 which is an amstrong number, the return statement has to return the sum as 370. I need to achieve this by functional programming only. How can I change the value 3 to be dynamic and equal to the number of digits.

```
return String.valueOf(number).chars().mapToObj(e -> Character.getNumericValue(e)).collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .reduce(0, (sum,value) -> {
            sum += (int)Math.pow(value, 3);
            return sum;
        });
```

Comment: use `Math.log10()`

Comment: Check this, might be helpful https://gist.github.com/artlovan/e8c1151939ad1f7ef42e710a921811ad